# GET aws lambda functions list using rest

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to write a unit test for the availability of AWS lambda functions. Is there any way to GET AWS lambdas list. I know using CMD we can get the list of AWS function. But I want any other way to get the lambda functions list.
After research, I find out a rest API of all AWS services. But I didn't understand how to use them.

I found out AWS HTTP calls, links are attached  `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html.`

Comment: The preferable method is to use an AWS SDK for your favourite language, which allows you to directly call AWS services. This is simpler than constructing a REST request. Have you tried this method?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that using AWS Infrastructure REST API interface.

To do so,

1. You first need to create a signature 4 authentication key for every call you make.

   - Reference: [Authenticating Requests (AWS Signature Version 4)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html)
2. Then you need to pass it via Authorization header in any REST request.

   - Reference: [Authenticating Requests: Using the Authorization Header (AWS Signature Version 4)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html)
3. Finally, call using ListFunctions API.

   - Reference: [ListFunctions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_ListFunctions.html)

Call Example:

> GET
>   /2015-03-31/functions/?FunctionVersion=FunctionVersion&Marker=Marker&MasterRegion=MasterRegion&MaxItems=MaxItems
>   HTTP/1.1

This gives you the list of Lambda functions deployed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Consider i want to write a unit test, which can compare all stages api gateway, and return if any API-gateway missing in any stage.

Comment: Beyond the scope of the question asked.